# Application stopped when button pressed twice android

Tags: android, crash

i have recently started android development and facing the error of unfortunaltely application has stopped. The application is quite simple it fetches the feeds from twitter when a button is pressed and display it in a textbox. The error occurs when the button is pressed multiple times. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.newsfeed;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NewsFeed extends Activity {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mTask;
    String jsonString;
    String url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=50cent&count=3";
    Button b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_feed);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getFeedBtn);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newsfeedEdit);

        mTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> () {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    jsonString = getJsonFromServer(url);
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                try {
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                    String text="";


                    for( int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++ ) {
                        JSONObject e = (JSONObject) jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        JSONObject f = (JSONObject) jArray.getJSONObject(i).get("user");

                        text = text + "User : "+f.getString("name")+"\n";

                        text = text + "ID : "+e.getString("id")+"\n";
                        text = text + "SOURCE: "+e.getString("source")+"\n";
                        text = text + "TEXT : "+e.getString("text")+"\n";
                    }
                    tv.setText(text);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mTask.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public static String getJsonFromServer(String url) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader inputStream = null;

        URL jsonUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection dc = jsonUrl.openConnection();

        dc.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        dc.setReadTimeout(5000);

        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                dc.getInputStream()));

        String jsonResult = inputStream.readLine();
        return jsonResult;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_news_feed, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is my logcat:

```
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:578)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.example.newsfeed.NewsFeed$2.onClick(NewsFeed.java:83)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-12 11:01:17.172: E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can we have logcat please?

Comment: i have updated my question with logcat

Comment: can you please google your exception before asking a question ?

Comment: i have googled my problem but didnt find anything helpful... thats why i asked here

Comment: use AsyncTask or disable the button whenever you click on the button until the operation over... @ShayanHusaini

Comment: @Venkat its happening even when the process is finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `onClick` method you have to check whether your task is already running. If you try to start a task multiple times, then your app will crash. I would suggest that you separate the declaration of your task into a private class and then instatiate that class in the onClick method (after you have checked whether it's running or not).

You can refer to the [AsyncTask documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more details. There are examples there as well.

I modified your code to re-create the task if the button is clicked subsequently. Find it [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5607547/). You will have to rework it a bit, since it doesn't make sense to cancel it all the time, but I decided to give an example anyway on how to do it.

Comment: but it also happened when the task is finished i mean when the data is displayed in the textbox... do i need to destroy any objects?

Comment: Yes, you have to create a whole new task if the old one has already completed or has been canceled. That's why I suggested to separate it in a class of its own.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, When you click on the Button it will execute the asyntask, if you try to click multiple times on the button it also executes the task multiple times and get crashed. So disable the button at the executing period.